# deleting line with a string and previous line in multiple files

Tags: sed

I want to remove all the lines that have 'n-----' in them and line before it. I have managed to do it in one file with:

```
 sed -i '' -n '/n-----/{s/.*//;x;d;};x;p;${x;p;}' FileName.fasta | sed '/^$/d'
```

But trying this with multiple files screws something up in some files, like adding line that weren't there before:

```
 sed -i '' -n '/n-----/{s/.*//;x;d;};x;p;${x;p;}' *.fasta | sed '/^$/d'
```

I guess there is something wrong in the syntax since I am using a pipeline but not sure what. Should be something simple I guess.
Many thanks!

Comment: could you add samples of your input files and expected output please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you have the following input files:

**INPUT:**

```
$ more file*.in
::::::::::::::
file2.in
::::::::::::::
u
v
w
n----- to remove
u
v
w
n----- to remove
u
::::::::::::::
file.in
::::::::::::::
a
b
c
n----- to remove
a
b
c
n----- to remove
a
```

**COMMAND:**

**TAKE A BACKUP OF YOUR FILES BEFORE TESTING IT!!!**

```
$ for f in `grep -l "^n-----" *.in`; do echo "processing file: $f"; sed -n '/n-----/{s/.*//;x;d;};x;p;${x;p;}' "$f" | sed '/^$/d' > "${f}.out" && mv "${f}.out" "$f"; done
processing file: file2.in
processing file: file.in
```

**Explanations:**

for all input files that contain lines that start with `^n-----` it will run the `sed`command and it will redirect the output of the `sed` to a tmp file and move it back to the original file (overwritten) if the `sed` command finishes successfully.

**OUTPUT:**

```
$ more file*.in
::::::::::::::
file2.in
::::::::::::::
u
v
u
v
u
::::::::::::::
file.in
::::::::::::::
a
b
a
b
a
```

Answer (score 1):

For gnu sed,

```
sed -s
```

treats every file as a single, separate file.

For example, if you have 3 identical files a, b and c-no.txt:

```
cat *-no.t?t
1
2
3

1
2
3

1
2
3
```

Without -s, the following command will delete the lines from line 3 in file a, containing a 3, to the next file b to delete line 1 and so for files b/c and in c from 3 to end of file:

```
sed '/3/,/1/d'  *-no.t?t
1
2
2
2
```

With -s, each file is treated as singular entity, so in each file, after end of file, no matching line 1 is searched for:

```
sed -s '/3/,/1/d'  *-no.t?t
1
2
1
2
1
2
```

The syntax for multiple options and parameters is not special, you can use

```
sed -i -s 
sed -s -i 
sed -is 
sed -si
```

and build more variations with more options/parameters.

Comment: I am using OSX. Seems to not be working, where would you put the -s flag in the sed -i '' -n '/n-----/{s/.*//;x;d;};x;p;${x;p;}' *.fasta | sed '/^$/d' command?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i 'N;/\nn---/d;P;D' file1 file2 ...
```

This creates a two line window throughout the file and deletes both lines if the second begins `n---`. The `-i` edits the files in place creating a temporary file and renaming it the original following the editing.